# Google Sheets ArrayFormula with Query and SELECT SUM only returns 1 single value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to populate a column on a Google Sheet with the `SUM` of the values in a specific column on another sheet where the identifier in a column matches. For reasons I'm struggling to understand, all I get at the moment is the word 'sum' written into the cell where the formula is and then a single value beneath it. It is failing to copy the formula down the remainder of the column.

The formula looks like this:

`=ArrayFormula(Query(Purchases!A2:S, "SELECT SUM(K) WHERE E = '" & C3 &"'"))`

I originally wanted to use `IMPORTRANGE` to query the data directly but thought that was part of the problem so I am doing that on another tab and then my formula above is referencing the tab with the imported data - is that a part of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

try aggregating it with `group by` like:

```
=QUERY(Purchases!A2:S, 
 "select E,sum(K) 
  where K is not null 
  group by E 
  label sum(K)''")
```

Comment: That will surely mean it return 2 columns a will overwrite the next column in my sheet too which I don't want. I don't need column E in the output?

Comment: @ProNotion in that case you will need to match it with C column within VLOOKUP... hard to guess like this but try in row 3: `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C3:C, QUERY(Purchases!A2:S, 
 "select E,sum(K) 
  where K is not null 
  group by E 
  label sum(K)''"), 2, 0)))`